# For a 2GBytes memory, suppose its memory width is 8 bits: what is the address space of the memory?

Tags: cpu-architecture

For a 2GBytes memory, suppose its memory width is 8 bits….
    what is the address space of the memory?
    what is the address width of the memory?

I’m not looking for the answer to question, I’m just trying to understand the process of how to get there.

Comment: Schoolar / homework question...

Comment: So... What are you looking for? I bet this is a University Test too. How did you get there? This is not kind of question you can do here sua vaquinha. - PRINTED -

Comment: @ErasmoOliveira Your point? I'm not trying to get an answer to the question as specifically said. I'm simply trying to understand something that I have been researching for hours.

Comment: @bcesars My bad thought this was somewhere others could help. Im just trying to understand the process to figure out the address space & address width. I don't understand it I have been reading things online and watching youtube tutorials but still am not understanding it.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** all instances of `Gb` replaced with `GB`

The address-space is the same as the memory size. This was not true (for example) in 32 bit operating systems that had more than 2^32 bytes of memory installed. Since the number of bits used for addressing is not specified in your question, one can only assume it to be sufficient to address the installed memory. To contrast, while you could install more than 4GB in a 32 bit system, you couldn't access more than 4GB, since (2^32)-1 is the location of the last byte you could access. Bear in mind, this address-space must include video memory and any/all bioses in the system. This meant that in 32bit WinXP MS limited the amount of user-accessible memory to a figure considerably less than 4GB.

Since the memory width is 8 bits, each address will point to 1 byte. Since you've got 2GB, you need to use a number of bits for addressing that is equal-to or greater-than that which will allow you to point to any one of those bytes.

Spoiler:

> Your address-space is 2GB and you need 31 bit wide addresses to use it all.